# passing list to a function in a class

Tags: python, list, function

I'm learning Python. I'm not sure how to pass a list to function in a class. Here is my example:

```
class Solution:

    def fn_one(self, strs = []):
        print(strs[0])
        return strs[0]


strs = ["ab", "abc", "abcs", "abx"]
x = Solution.fn_one(strs)
```

The output:

> IndexError: list index out of range

like I'm passing an empty list. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a class here? Your class has no internal state, it is pointless. Also, you don't instantiate an instance of it, and rather, just try to call the function on the class directly, so `strs` is being passed to `self` (since it is literally just the function you defined). Finally, you should take care when using a mutable object as a default value, default values are evaluated *once* at *function definition time*. If you mutate that default value, mutations will be seen on every call that uses the default value...

Comment: You should start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

Because `fn_one` is an instance method, so you're passing `strs` as `self`, you can create an instance of `Solution` for it to be passed as self, and `strs` to be passed as the `strs` list:

```
x = Solution().fn_one(strs)
```

Output:

```
ab
```

Unless this is not what you want, you can define `fn_one` as a static method using the `@staticmethod` decorator:

```
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def fn_one(strs = []):  #  here, nothing is passed automatically
        print(strs[0])
        return strs[0]

X = Solution.fn_one(strs)
#   Solution().fn_one(strs) would work also, since nothing is passed automatically
```

Or, as a class method, using the `@classmethod` decorator:

```
class Solution:
    @classmethod
    def fn_one(cls, strs = []):  #  here, the class is passed automatically as `cls`
        print(strs[0])
        return strs[0]

X = Solution.fn_one(strs)
```

But if neither the class nor an object is necessary for the method to work properly, using a static method is the best way to go. And if your class doesn't have any methods in it that work with objects, then a class isn't necessary, just use a function instead.

Comment: "But if neither the class nor an object is necessary for the method to work properly, using a static method is the best way to go." The *best* way to go in that case is not to use a method at all...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're right, what I meant was the method `fn_one`, there are probably other methods not shown in the code that work with instances.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `@classmethod` decorator above the `fn_one` method or instantiate the class first like so: `x = Solution().fn_one(strs)`

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instace before use `fn_one` method. Like this:

**Code:**

```
strs = ["ab", "abc", "abcs", "abx"]
x = Solution()
x.fn_one(strs)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
ab
```

Or you can do it in one line if you put the parentheses after your class. Like this:

**Code:**

```
strs = ["ab", "abc", "abcs", "abx"]
x = Solution().fn_one(strs)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
ab
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling fn_one as if were a static method so you inside your method `self` receive the list of strings.

You have several options:

Create an instance of `Solution`

```py
solution = Solution()
x = solution.fn_one(strs)
```

Or change the class definition so fn_one is a static method

```
class Solution:
    @staticmethod
    def fn_one(strs=[]):
        print(strs[0])
        return strs[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

First create the instance of solution class & call the fn_one() function with its reference.

**Code :**

```
class Solution:

    def fn_one(self, strs):
        print(strs[0])
        return strs[0]


strs = ["ab", "abc", "abcs", "abx"]
x = Solution().fn_one(strs)
```

**Output :**

```
ab
```